# differential equation $y''(x)-ay^3(x)+by(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am trying to find a solution $y(x)$ to this non linear differential equation
$$
y''(x)-ay^3(x)+by(x)=0.
$$
I know a nice solution exists, however how can I go about solving this?  I know non linear ODE's a are tougher than linaer ODE's, however this one has such a closed form solution I thought maybe it would be straight forward.

I can verify that a solution exists , we can write it in the general form
$$
y(x)=A \tanh cx,\quad y''(x)=2c^2A\tanh cx(\tanh^2 cx-1).
$$
We can simply verify this works by plugging into the ODE to obtain$$
2c^2A\tanh^3 cx-2c^2A\tanh cx-aA^3\tanh^3 cx+bA\tanh cx=0,\quad a,b\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
We can see this is true if 
$$
2c^2 A=aA^3,\quad 2c^2A=bA,\to A=\sqrt\frac{2c^2}{a}=\sqrt \frac{b}{a},\quad c=\sqrt \frac{b}{2}.
$$
We can now see
$
y(x)=A\tanh cx 
$ is a solution for these values of A and c.

Now how can we solve this differential equation and obtain y(x)?  Thanks for reading this and thinking about it

Comment: Try $y_2(x) = f(x)y(x)$  for some $f$ and see if something works out when you sub it into the ODE.

Comment: The cube term foils $fy$. I wonder if there is a proof somewhere that states this method only works for linear equation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is
$$
y''-ay^3+by=0.
$$
Make a substitution
$$
u(y)=y',
$$
which implies that
$$
y''=u'u.
$$
You get the equation
$$
u'u=ay^3-by,
$$
which integrates to
$$
\frac{u^2}{2}=\frac{ay^4}{4}-\frac{by^2}{2}+C_1,
$$
or
$$
u=\pm\sqrt{\frac{ay^4}{2}-by^2+C_1}\,.
$$
Now you end up with the equation
$$
y'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{ay^4}{2}-by^2+C_1},
$$
which is obviously a separable equation, but the closed form solutions exist only for specific values of $a,b,C_1$.

Comment: Artem, before I check it as answer.  I am going to verify it all myself right now.  Okay?  Thanks a lot for the reply in fast!!!

Comment: For what values of a,b $C_1$ can we obtain the solution $y(x)\propto \tanh x$?  Thanks.

Comment: I think that the only case when you can evaluate this integral without resorting to elliptic functions is $C_1=0$.

Comment: Yes Artem, I realized that.  But for that case I obtain 
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{ay^2}{2}-by^2}}=-\frac{x\sqrt{ax^2-2b}}{\sqrt b \sqrt{ax^4-bx^2}}\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{\sqrt{2b}}{\sqrt{ax^2-2b}}\big).
$$

Comment: This is probably not you who obtained, but Mathematica. Plus you have $y$ on the left and $x$ on the right. The expression on the right can be simplified. Remember, than Mathematica does not know what the values of $a$ and $b$ and assume that they are complex. The same about $y$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write $$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{ay^2}{2}-by^2}}=-\frac{y\sqrt{ay^2-2b}}{\sqrt b \sqrt{ay^4-by^2}}\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{\sqrt{2b}}{\sqrt{ay^2-2b}}\big)=x.$$
But how can we get $y(x)\propto \tanh x$? from this solution?Thanks.  And yes similar to how you realized it was elliptic functions, I used mathematica.  How do simplify this result? It is obvious that we will try to simplify it of the form
$$
\tanh^{-1} y= x,\to y=\tanh x.
$$
Any suggestions?  Thanks for your time again..

Comment: Take $C_1$ such that $ay^2/2-by+C_1$ is a full square.

Comment: @Downvoter Is it possible to point out why the answer is not helpful? :)

Answer (score 2):

Maple 18 finds the solution in terms of a Jacobi elliptic function:
$$y \left( x \right) =C_{{2}}\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {b}{a{C_{{2}}}^{2}-a
+2\,b}}}{\it JacobiSN} \left(  \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {-2\,a+4\,b}x+C_{{1}}
 \right) \sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {b}{a{C_{{2}}}^{2}-a+2\,b}}},{\frac {C
_{{2}}\sqrt {- \left( a-2\,b \right) a}}{a-2\,b}} \right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

In the Ginzburg-Landau theory, the above equation can be obtained by deriving the Gibbs Free Energy and by setting it equal to zero. The solution can explain the behavior of the order parameter close to the normal-superconductor interface. Since deep inside the superconductor the density of super-electron is constant, one can apply the boundary condition u=0 for x-->inf. Applying this condition to the above equation (the fifth counting from the top) one can easily found that C = 1/2 and the solution can be written in its closed form.